# Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity when trying to execute a post request

Tags: post, request, httpclient

I am trying to make a `post` request from an third party application to `AEM`, but i am trying to execute the following code :

```
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
        at script1512480346647.run(script1512480346647.groovy:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.runtime.support.ScriptExecutorSupport.invokeMethod(ScriptExecutorSupport.java:158)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.runtime.support.ScriptExecutorSupport.execute(ScriptExecutorSupport.java:126)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.runtime.support.ScriptExecutorSupport.execute(ScriptExecutorSupport.java:73)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.execute.ExecuteMojo.process(ExecuteMojo.java:249)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.ComponentMojoSupport.doExecute(ComponentMojoSupport.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.MojoSupport.execute(MojoSupport.java:69)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:226)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
```

Does anybody have an idea about what is the problem?  Actually the `post` request also contains a `zip` file attached.